# Is it possible to filter the list of fields when outputting a Full Dataset?

Tags: report, flexcel

I have a DataTable that I'm passing to a FlexCel report. It contains a variable number of columns, so I'm using the Full Dataset feature (e.g. `<#table_name.*>`).

However, only a subset of the fields are dynamically generated (I have a variable number of attachments). The column name for each attachment field starts with a common word (e.g. "Attachment0", "Attachment1", etc).

What I would like to do is output the known finite set of fields and then the variable number of attachments. It would be nice if I could write something like `<#table_name.Attachment*>` (and `<#table_name.Attachment**>`). Is there any way in FlexCel Reports I can achieve the same result?

A side benefit to such a solution means that I could keep the formatting for the known/finite set of fields.

**Update**

I added place holder columns to the document, each with a `<#delete column>` tag, so that the un-wanted columns/data are removed.

Although this works, it's not ideal. For example, if I want to see how the columns fit in the page width (in print preview), then I need to hide the columns. Then I have to remember to un-hide them again, so other developers can see/understand my handy work.

It would be much more straight forward if I could filter the fields before they're output to the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised there's an alternate way around this problem. I broke up the data into two sets of data - `<#table_name.*>` and `<#table_name_attachments.*>`.

The fixed set of fields are in the first table and the variable set of fields is in the second table (all the "Attachment*" fields). When the report is run, I place them next to each other (in the same order) in the same worksheet. This means I have two table ranges - `"_table_name_"` and `"_table_name_attachments_"` on the one sheet.

Now I'm able to run my print preview without hiding/re-showing the columns-to-be-deleted. I've also eliminated human error - it was all to easy to accidentally set the wrong number of padded/delete columns.